# Custom TableViewCell with dynamic height and full width image using Autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, tableview, uitableview

I'm really stuck using autolayout and a custom tableviewcell.

I want my tableviewcell to have a dynamic height. The table cell should contain an image with the same width as the tableviewcell and the height should adjust based on an aspect ratio of 0.6

[This is what it should look like](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ai8zxpe6eo2e9nm/whatiwant.png?dl=0)

[But this is what I get](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fqnoly13tqx7xsm/whatiget.png?dl=0)

To give you a clear look of what is going on I gave the tableViewCell and it's subviews some pretty background colors…

- Green = thumbnailView
- Blue = self
- Red = contentView
- Purple = hotspotNameLabel
- Yellow = categoryLabel

This is what my code looks like:

**Initializer:**

```
- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier{
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {

    self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    CGFloat imageAspectRatio = 720/432;
    CGFloat imageHeight = self.contentView.bounds.size.width / imageAspectRatio;

    CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.contentView.bounds.size.width,imageHeight);

    self.thumbnailView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageFrame];
    [self.thumbnailView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    [self.thumbnailView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
    [self.thumbnailView.layer setMasksToBounds:true];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.thumbnailView];

    self.hotspotNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 15, self.contentView.bounds.size.width - 80, 20)];
    [self.hotspotNameLabel setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
    [self.hotspotNameLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:(32/255.0) alpha:1]];
    [self.hotspotNameLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    [self.hotspotNameLabel setNumberOfLines:0]; // Unlimited Lines
    [self.hotspotNameLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
    [self.hotspotNameLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-Medium" size:20]];

    [self.contentView addSubview:self.hotspotNameLabel];

    // Category Label
    self.categoryLabel = [[CategoryLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 15, self.contentView.bounds.size.width - 80, 10)
                                                   categoryId:22 categoryName:@"Food"];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.categoryLabel];

    // Constraints

    [self.contentView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:false];
    [self.hotspotNameLabel setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:false]; // Enables autosizing
    [self.categoryLabel setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:false];
    [self.thumbnailView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:false];

    [self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.thumbnailView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: self.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1.0f constant:0]];
    [self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.thumbnailView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: self.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:0.6f constant:0]];

    [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[nameLabel]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"nameLabel": self.hotspotNameLabel}]];
    [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[thumbnail]-20-[nameLabel]-10-[categoryLabel]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"thumbnail": self.thumbnailView,@"nameLabel": self.hotspotNameLabel, @"categoryLabel":self.categoryLabel}]];


}
return self;}
```

**Layout subviews:**

```
-(void)layoutSubviews {

[super layoutSubviews];

[self.contentView setNeedsLayout];
[self.contentView layoutIfNeeded];


self.hotspotNameLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.hotspotNameLabel.bounds);
}
```

**tableView:HeightForRowAtIndexPath**:

```
    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return [self heightForLargeCellAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}

- (CGFloat)heightForLargeCellAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    LargeHotspotCell *sizingCell = [[LargeHotspotCell alloc] init];

    [self configureLargeCell:sizingCell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    [sizingCell setNeedsLayout];
    [sizingCell layoutIfNeeded];

    CGFloat height = [sizingCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;

    return height + 1 ;
}
```

Comment: is it necessary to add contraints through code? it is much easier to do it in storyboard

Comment: @NeilGaliaskarov I also tried, but I couldn't get it done with storyboards either :s

Comment: I can post here some sample project with basic concepts. can you provide your heightForRowAtIndexPath method implementation

Comment: @NeilGaliaskarov I added it to my question :-)

Comment: Pls, check my answer and dont forget to mark it accepted if it resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are my little tutorial with explaining basic concepts of autolayout.
Your first step, should be subclassing `UITableviewCell`, I named my new cell `DynamicTableViewCell` and assigned it in the identity inspector.

[image]

I dragged and dropped UILabel and UIImageView into contentView. 
Below a screenshot with UILabel constraints, I added simultaneously leading and trailing space constraints, in order to make my label equal to contentView width. And it is aligned to the bottom of the cell.

[image]

Now, it is time to assign constraints to UIImageView. I am adding aspect ratio 0.6 (imageHeight/imageWidth = 0.6) and adding leading and trailing space to contentView. Feel free to play with constants to achieve your desired purposes.

[image]

**Final results in iphone5, iphone6 simulator**

Your image height (green color) is 60pt in 5s screen, 70pt in 6 screen and width resized properly:

[image]

For your better understanding, I am publishing [Working Sample Project on github](https://github.com/gneil90/dynamicHeightCell)

Comment: Based on your screenshot of iPhone5 vs iPhone6, I can see that the image is scaled properly but the tableviewcells height didn't change. The label underneath can have multiple lines (so this should also influencers the cell's height) and should be aligned to the bottom of the image. I think your label is now displaying above the image. :-/

Comment: I made the height of cell equal for all cells, further customization is on your side.

Comment: Yes but I was already able to do this but then I can't get the text to display underneath the image… The moment i want to position the labels under thie image like this: `[self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[thumbnail]-[nameLabel]-[categoryLabel]-10-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"thumbnail": self.thumbnailView,@"nameLabel": self.hotspotNameLabel,@"categoryLabel": self.categoryLabel}]];` then it looks good but I get the following error (see next comment)

Comment: 015-07-29 09:19:41.992 appName[6760:1818580] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
 Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want…